# How to get rid of language specific counterparts of Re: Fwd: etc. from Lotus Notes e-mail subjects?

Tags: email, thunderbird, lotus-notes

It is possible to configure Lotus Notes to not use prefixes of country specific language counterparts of `Re:` `Fwd:` e.t.c. in e-mail subjects?

It is possible to automagically cleanup chains:

`PREFIX: (language specific PREFIX: counterpart) PREFIX: ...`

of this kind when replying to or before sending e-mails in Thunderbird?

How to just stop this madness?!?

Comment: There is `mailnews.localizedRe` (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Reply_indicators), but it looks like recent versions of Thunderbird ignore this setting (like many others).

Answer (score 0):

There are Thunderbird add-ones:

- [Subject Cleaner](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/subject-cleaner/) - remove extra strings from the subject while composing the message. ***RegEx rules.***
- [Clean Subject](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/clean-subject/) - cleans the subject from multiple occurrences of subject prefixes such as ("Re: Re-2: Re:") and postfixes that are inserted by other clients. Words like "[SPAM]" can be cleaned as well. These prefixes can be defined in the preferences. ***Abandoned :|***

allowing for email subjects clean-up...

Comment: Subject Cleaner is also abandoned with regard to current Thunderbird versions.